# Is this code achieving what I want?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am attempting to create a query which evaluates who the owner of a particular vehicle is at a point in time.  Sightings of vehicles are contained in the `vehicle_sightings` table.  What is slightly tricky about this query, is that the vehicle_vrn and vehicle_ownership tables are historical.  So what I need to do is obtain the VRN and owner of a vehicle, at the point of the sighting (based on the `seenDate` field in the vehicle_sightings table.

```
SELECT 
    sighting_id
FROM
    vehicle_sightings
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_vrn ON vehicle_sightings.plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno
        INNER JOIN
    vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
WHERE
    vehicle_sightings.seenDate >= vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date
        AND (vehicle_sightings.seenDate <= vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date IS NULL
        OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY sighting_id
    HAVING seenDate >= MAX(ownership_start_date);
```

I have tried many variants of the above query, but none of them seem to have had the desired results, except for the one pasted above.  What I am worried about, however, is that it is not really working as I want it to, as I do not have much experience with `GROUP BY` statements.

What I want, therefore is that in a case like the screenshot below, the record whose `ownership_start_date` is closest to the `seenDate`, to be used, and the others to be ignored.  Also, in cases where an end_date has been specified, those are of no concern.  This scenario is only present where no end_date is specified, and there are more than 1 historical entries.

Am I on the right track?  Does this query make sense?  And does it take the `vehicle_vrn` historical data into account too, as there can also be cases where there are multiple entries for the same vrn, but with different `vrn_start_dates`.

[image]

Comment: sorry for my english. but sighting mean `was seen`? can you prepare a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with the schema?

Comment: I try read the rest of your question and isnt clear to me what you want. You need include a bigger sample data and based on that data explain what should be the desire result. Also need to include your db schema.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there.  However, your `HAVING` clause won't have any effect (the latest `ownership_start_date` in each group will necessarily be before the `seenDate`, since you have explicitly required that of every constituent record in the `WHERE` clause).

What you're after is the [group-wise maximum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be obtained by joining your grouped results back to the underlying table.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle_ownership JOIN (
  SELECT
      vehicle_sightings.*,
      vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno,
      MAX(vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date) AS ownership_start_date
  FROM
      vehicle_sightings
          INNER JOIN
      vehicle_vrn ON vehicle_sightings.plate = vehicle_vrn.vrnno
          INNER JOIN
      vehicle_ownership ON vehicle_vrn.fk_sysno = vehicle_ownership.fk_sysno
  WHERE
      vehicle_sightings.seenDate >= vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date
          AND (vehicle_sightings.seenDate <= vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date
          OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date IS NULL
          OR vehicle_ownership.ownership_end_date = '0001-01-01 00:00:00')
  GROUP BY sighting_id
) t USING (fk_sysno, ownership_start_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have actually never seen the 'using'  statement before - does it help achieve what I am after?

Comment: @DotNET: `a JOIN b USING (col)` is essentially just shorthand for `a JOIN b ON a.col = b.col` (except that `col` without a table-qualifier won't be ambiguous in the result).  What's helping you achieve what you're after, as explained in my answer, is the join of the grouped result back onto the `vehicle_ownership` table.

Comment: Great, I will give it a try! Does it also cater for the vehicle_vrn historical values too? As besides taking the vehicle_start_date which is closest to seenDate, it also needs to take the vrn500 value whose vrn_start_date is closest to the seenDate

Comment: @DotNET: No, I haven't accounted for that.  It's a bit difficult for me to picture exactly what's happening without some sample data... though I imagine you'll need to further restrict the join on `vehicle_vrn` according to the date in much the same way as you are doing with `vehicle_ownership.ownership_start_date`.

Comment: Could you explain why fk_sysno and ownership_start_date are both used in the USING? fk_sysno is an integer column and ownership_start_date is a date column

Comment: @DotNET: Because both columns are required to identify the matching record—otherwise one would end up joining ownership records for every car that happens to have commenced on the relevant date.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Unfortunately the suggested code is omitting some records and I am not sure why.  I will attempt to dissect the query.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions? I am only getting around half of the correct records.

Comment: @DotNET: It's a bit difficult for me to picture exactly what's happening without some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. What sample data would you like me to provide?

Comment: Edited the question with the data :)

Comment: @DotNET:  That's neither complete nor verifiable.

Comment: I cannot provide more than that though as it is sensitive data. The data also does not vary more than that - it is more of the same.

Comment: @DotNET: Did you even read the link I gave?  It has suggestions for how to handle exactly that situation.

Comment: Will be sending the create and insert statements with some sample data shortly.

Comment: I have added both the CREATE and INSERT statements - please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @DotNET: Your schema contained a few errors that prevented it from running, which I have corrected (together with modifications to my query that enable it to run against that schema) in [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a570e0/3/0).  What records do you expect in the resultset that are missing from this example?

Comment: Could you also modify the SQL to check for the same condition on the vehicle_vrn table? i.e. It also gets the sysno value for the vrn where the ownership_start_date is closest to the seenDate.

Comment: @DotNET: It's a bit difficult for me to picture exactly what's happening.  What records do you expect in the resultset that are missing from this example?

Comment: I cannot see a pattern of the records which are not matching.  I know that i have 5,000 unique records which should be returned by the query, however it is actually returning 5033.  So there are 33 which are repeated. I am suspecting that this is an unrelated issue, so for the sake of this question I will accept your answer.  Thanks a lot for your assistance.